# ExpressionEngine: Pass parameter into variable tag pair and fetch in the function

Tags: php, expressionengine

I need to pass parameter into inner tag, ex.

```
{exp:myplugin:func}
  {last_year subject="xxx"}

  {/last_year}
{/exp:myplugin:func}
```

How can I fetch that parameter in the function?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?  Is there something in the documentation that is unclear: https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/plugins.html

Comment: @AllInOne - the documentation doesn't cover parameters in variable pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function I've written to return the parameters for a variable pair inside a template tag pair:

```
private function get_variable_parameters($tagData, $varName) {
    $parameters = array();

    if (strpos($tagData, LD."/".$varName.RD) !== FALSE) {
        //###   Closing variable tag exists   ###
        if (preg_match_all("/".LD.$varName."(.*?)".RD."(.*?)".LD."\/".$varName.RD."/s", $tagData, $matches)) {
            for ($num = 0; $num < count($matches[0]); $num++){
                $allParams = explode(" ", trim($matches[1][$num]));
                foreach($allParams as $value) {
                    $value = str_replace(array('"', "'"), '', $value);
                    $param = explode("=", $value);
                    if (!empty($param[1]))
                        $parameters[$param[0]] = $param[1];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $parameters;
}//###   End of get_variable_parameters function   ###
```

So from your example code in your func method:

```
$tagData = ee()->TMPL->tagdata;
$varParameters = $this->get_variable_parameters($tagData, "last_year");
echo $varParameters["subject"];
```

Looking back over my code though, I don't think it handles multiple use of the same variable pair inside the same loop, so if required may need to change this line:

```
$parameters[$param[0]] = $param[1];
```

to:

```
$parameters[$num][$param[0]] = $param[1];
```

And then work out what instance of the variable pairs inside the same loop. Untested though, probably needs more work!